# Wordpress woo-commerce get_post_meta if/else hangs the page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom field in a woocommerce template.  The values from the select box are 0 and 1.

If I put this in my product template file it will echo 1 or 0 depending on the selection made

```
<?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_select', true ); ?>
```

However I want to echo out a different button depending on the value with and if/else statement.  When I try this the page just hangs and won't load with the following code...

```
<h1>

<?php 

$grade = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_select', true ); 

if ($grade == true) {
 echo "<a class="button small secondary" title="" href="">True</a>";
} 
else if ($grade == false){
 echo "<a class="button small secondary" title="" href="">False</a>";   
}

?>
</h1>
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: did you try to get it as a string ? $grade == 'true' . or $grade == 1 ?

Comment: Idea: $grade is neither true nor false (null maybe?)
Sound silly? Easy to test. Make your 'else if' clause an 'else'. Then you are assured one or the other echo will get executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should change your double quote to a single like below and all will be fine.

```
if ($grade == true) {
 echo "<a class='button small secondary' title='' href=''>True</a>";
} 
else if ($grade == false){
 echo "<a class='button small secondary' title='' href=''>False</a>";   
}
```